# How can I filter the values of a foreign key field based on another foreign key field value in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-filter

These are my models:

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=350, verbose_name=_('name'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('is active'))

class ProductSpecification(models.Model):
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='specifications',
                                     verbose_name=_('product type'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('name'))

class Product(models.Model):
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, related_name='products', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True,
                                     blank=True, verbose_name=_('product type'))

class ProductSpecificationValue(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='specs_values',
                                verbose_name=_('product'))
    specification = models.ForeignKey(ProductSpecification, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='specs_values',
                                      verbose_name=_('specification'))
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('value'))
```

and in admin.py:

```
class ProductSpecificationTabu(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductSpecification
    fields = ('name_en', 'name_fa',)

@admin.register(ProductType)
class ProductTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('name_en', 'name_fa',)
    inlines = (ProductSpecificationTabu,)
    search_fields = ('name_en', 'name_fa',)

class ProductSpecificationValueTabu(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductSpecificationValue
    fields = ('specification', 'value_en', 'value_fa',)
    autocomplete_fields = ('specification',)

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('product_type', )
    inlines = (ProductSpecificationValueTabu, )
```

I want to limit the options for the 'ProductSpecificationValueTabu' based on the selected 'product_type' when choosing the product_type for a product.

Should I do this using javascript?